# On executing PHP script in command line, it returns a webscript enclosed in script tags

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

As the title suggests, I am trying to execute a PHP file on linux command line and it is working fine, I am actually running PHP script to post a status on Facebook graph API, and on executing the script I am getting a webscript enclosed within a script tag,the response I get, how do I execute the response? how do I execute it automatically with out using a browser?

My final aim is to use the the cron tab to schedule the posting of a facebook status by  calling this PHP script.

PHP CODE FOR POSTING

```
> $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '1784504901790451',
  'app_secret' => '4b7b2673ecd268b962b0f25166955f23',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

> $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'publish_actions']; // optional
try {
        if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
                $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
        } else {
                $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
 }
if (isset($accessToken)) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
                $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        } else {
                $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
                // OAuth 2.0 client handler
                $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
                // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
                $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
 $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
                $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        }

        // validating the access token
        try {
                $request = $fb->get('/me');
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                // When Graph returns an error
                if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
                        unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
                        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
                        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/AutoPHPfb/', $permissions);
                        echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
                        exit;
                }
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
                echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;
        }

        // posting on user timeline using publish_actins permission
        try {
                // message must come from the user-end
            $data = [
  'message' => 'My awesome photo upload example.',
  'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('/var/www/bitvie.cloudapp.net/htdocs/AutoPHPfb/Photos/B612-2015-08-10-10-36-17.jpg'),
  // Or you can provide a remote file location
  //'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('https://example.com/photo.jpg'),
];
                $request = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data);
                $response = $request->getGraphNode();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                // When Graph returns an error
                echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
                echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
        }

        echo $response['id'];

        // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
        // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://bitvie.cloudapp.net/AutoPHPfb/PHPprofilepic.php', $permissions);
        echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
}
```

and here is the reponse I get

`<script>window.top.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=1784504901790451&state=4a090fd3336bc798d3604bc760538e3f&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.0.0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbitvie.cloudapp.net%2FAutoPHPfb%2FPHPprofilepic.php&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions'</script>`

Comment: Some sample code would really help us to help you here!

Comment: Are you trying to use the JS SDK through PHP? The JS SDK would only work inside a browser. If you want to stick with PHP, check out the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) if it supports what you're looking for.

Comment: "webscript"? as in a `<script>` block? You can't execute that in PHP, period. it's javascript...

Comment: Please re check the question now that I have added code.

Comment: How does the response look like? I doubt that facebook returns a `<script>` block

Comment: please check the edited version again.

Comment: So apparently facebook is not returning a `<script>` block, it's returning an URL. You are wrapping it inside `<script>`, that's not coming from facebook. I still don't understand what you want to do though.

Comment: when i  am executing the php file in the browser it redirects me to facebook (for the first time), to get the authentication, and then posts it nicely. But the same thing via command line is a problem.

Comment: Well because your scripts are executed in the browser but not on command line. You need to rewrite your php code and call the URLs manually. You could use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: You can not perform Facebook login in the background via command line, it has to happen in the browser.